# Changing Activities to Classes - Android

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I am somewhat new to Java and Android and I'm having trouble with classes and activities. I was cleaning up my code and moved a lot of it from my MainActivity to different classes, but I was only able to get the app to work by creating new activities instead of classes.

- I need to stay in the main view and just use the class's methods
- From the main activity a button, counts down and then calls the LocationActivity.
- LocationActivity finds the GPS coordinates and then sends them to SendActivity.

This is the only way I could get it to work because I just needed to start the locationListener, so I just started it in the onCreate section.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button mCloseButton;
    Button mOpenButton;
    MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer mDrawer;

    private Button send_button;
    Button sendButton;
    EditText msgTextField;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        send_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 

        mDrawer.open();

        mCloseButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                mDrawer.animateClose();
            }
        });

        mOpenButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                if( !mDrawer.isOpened() )
                    mDrawer.animateOpen();
            }
        });

        final SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("PEOPLE_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String first = shared.getString("FIRSTNAME", "");
        final String last = shared.getString("LASTNAME", "0");


       ///////Profile Button//////////////// 
        Button profile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class));
            }
        });
        ///////////////////////////////////

       //////Generate ID//////////////////
        if (usr_id == null) {

            char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABSDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".toCharArray();
            Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            char[] id = new char[8];
            for (int i = 0;  i < 8;  i++) {
                id[i] = chars[r.nextInt(chars.length)];
            }
            usr_id = new String(id);
            Editor editor = shared.edit();
            editor.putString("USR_ID", usr_id);
            editor.commit();
        }
        //////////////////////////////////                 

        ////////Send Alert////////////////
        ///////Begin Timer///////////////
        send_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private boolean running = false;
            private CountDownTimer timer;
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if(!running)
              {
                running = true;
                timer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        send_button.setText("SENT");  
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationActivity.class));
                        SendUserActivity.sendId(usr_id1, first, last);                                          
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long sec) {
                        send_button.setText("CANCEL (" + sec / 1000 + ")");

                    }
                }.start();
              }
              else
              {
                 timer.cancel();
                 send_button.setText("Send!");
                 running = false;
              }
            }
        });
    }  
    ///////////////////////////////////


    @Override
   public void onContentChanged()
   {
    super.onContentChanged();
    mCloseButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_open );
    mOpenButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_open );
    mDrawer = (MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer) findViewById( R.id.drawer );
   }
}
```

LocationActivity.java

```
    package com.alex.www;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {


    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startLocation();
    }

    void startLocation()
    {   

        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("PEOPLE_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String usr_id2 = shared.getString("USR_ID", "none");

    //get a reference to the LocationManager
    locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    //checked to receive updates from the position
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            SendActivity.send(location, usr_id2);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            //labelState.setText("Provider OFF");
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            //labelState.setText("Provider ON ");
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            Log.i("", "Provider Status: " + status);
            }
        };

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
}
```

SendActivity.java

```
    package com.alex.www;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SendActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void send(Location loc, String usr_id2)
    {

         Log.i("", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + " - " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));

         String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()); 
         String lon = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/test/example.php");

         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat)); 
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr_id2));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
         } 
         catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: With all due respect, go learn Java first, without the burden of learning Android at the same time. I'm sure you won't appreciate that piece of advice, but once you have a firm understanding of Java you'll understand that it was the best course of action for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your post for more clarity, since the question was interesting. This is a dilemma that many new developers have when they start with android. And trust me I have seen really bad code. And getting the right advice at the right time is important. So here goes.

You are on the right track. Every view must have its own activity. Dont get out of that habit. If you go the java way, then you are tempted to not use activity's, but that will make you a very bad android developer.

Yes, you do need to read a bit more on how to write a android app.

If you use 1 view 1 activity principle, android OS will support you a lot. For example, back button traversing back in sequence will be supported.

Comment: Whatever happen with Fragments?

Comment: Did not understand your question ?

Answer (score 0):

General approach would be:

Make them classes (remove *extends Activity*) and make contructors for both classes which accept context as parameter. Prepare your methods and in main activity make new instance of class so you can use it's methods. Probably you would need to adapt some things, but it shouldn't be a big problem.

btw: It is recommended that all long operations (like location update, http send/recieve) are managed using [threads/background operation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), so your UI is not frozen and you avoid ANR force closing..

Comment: Can you give me an example with my code? Just something to get me started. If I remove the extends Activity part from LocationActivity, `getSystemService` throws an error and asks me to create a method for it.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is a class. Said that if you need to do any operation that uses external services or does something potentially lengthy you much better off using AsyncTask that does it on it's own thread. Please [refer to this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for details